# Removing milliseconds from timestamp on specific columns

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I am trying to remove the milliseconds from both timestamps( columns 8 and 9)

```
1       20  2   14000   14000 11    1   10:11:56.136    10:11:56.136    0   1
```

I  have been using the following sed command to remove them:

```
 sed 's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)\.[0-9]\{3\}/\1/g'
```

This worked really well. However I noticed that in my file I have other time stamps where I only have two milliseconds and some with one millisecond:

```
**10:46:27.93   10:46:27.90** and some with only one millisecond 10:46:2     10:46:2
```

I ran my sed command again  in order to remove two milliseconds on the file that I had removed the  three milliseconds. Like this:

```
sed 's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)\.[0-9]\{2\}/\1/g'
```

This works fine because I see that it removes the two milliseconds from the time.

**Problem:**

After running the above command, I see that it is also sometimes modifying some of my other columns. I am not including all of my columns because it would be difficult to read. I have around 40 columns. I only want to modify the columns 8 and 9.

**Question**

How can I take care of all three cases with one command. When I say three cases I mean when having two milliseconds, one milliseconds and three milliseconds. Also, how can make sure I **ONLY** modify columns 8 and 9.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: Try to remove only from timestamps, use `'s/\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)\.[0-9]\{2,\}/\1/g'`. Else, try `'s/^\([[:blank:]]*\([^[:space:]]+[[:blank:]]+)\{7\}[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])\.[0-9]\{2,\}\([[:blank:]]+[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])\.[0-9]\{2,\}/\1\3/g'` (not sure, but you might also need to escape the `+`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wanna strip of the milliseconds from, if you time has similar format try this

```
sed -E 's/(:[0-9]+)\.[0-9]+/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a beginner in `awk`, so apologies if found less efficient.

```
awk '{gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$8);gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$9);print}' file
```

Will remove the milli-seconds value from columns 8 and 9 alone. The logic is straight forward.

- Removing any set of characters following a pattern `.` followed by any number of digits

In action:-

```
$ cat file
1       20  2   14000   14000 11    1   10:11:56.136    10:11:56.136    0   1

$ awk '{gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$8);gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$9);print}' file

1 20 2 14000 14000 11 1 10:11:56 10:11:56 0 1
```

Now column 7 changed to have a `.` value. See the action below

```
$ cat file
1       20  2   14000   14000 11    1.1   10:11:56.136    10:11:56.136    0   1

$ awk '{gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$8);gsub(/\.[0-9]*/,"",$9);print}' file

1 20 2 14000 14000 11 1.1 10:11:56 10:11:56 0 1
```

Column 7 remains unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your sed version, you can use:

```
sed -E 's/\.\d{1,3}//g'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/\.[0-9]{1,3}//g'
```

---

[Bash Demo](http://ideone.com/mu1i3m)

Answer (score 1):

In the current regex you specified precisely 3 digits with:

```
\{3\}
```

To make that between 1 and 3 digits you can write:

```
\{1,3\}
```

To replace in only the 8th and 9th column using sed is extremely difficult, if at all possible.
But a workaround might work for you, if we can make some assumptions:

- columns before the 8th will never match
- the 8th and 9th columns will always match

In this case, you can drop the `/g` flag, and apply the replacement twice per each line of input, that is:

```
sed -e cmd -e cmd
```

Where cmd is:

```
's/\(:[0-9][0-9]\)\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. It basically skips `7` columns using `(\S+\s+){7}` then fixes the following 2 columns:

```
sed -re 's/(\s*(\S+\s+){7})([^.]+)\.\S+([^.]+)\.\S+/\1\3\4/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem
I solved it with

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*//' source> destination
```